Looking for a bijection between the integers and finite binary strings
Let $A$ be the set of all finite binary strings. Example elements are "", "0", "1", "00", "01", ...
I'm looking for a bijection between the integers and $A$.
The application is for a number system able to represent each integer uniquely.

The bijection is simply rewriting the finite binary string in base $10$?

Is "0" different than "00"?

@AlkaKadri No because $00$ in base ten is $0$. But so is $000.$

An easy bijection between $A$ and the positive integers would be to prepend 1 to the string, and then take the integer with that binary representation.  Then, just compose with your favorite bijection between the integers and the positive integers.

@DanielSchepler you beat me. I was writing the same reply :)


prepend 1 to the string, and then take the integer with that binary representation

Ahh, that solves it, thanks!

Looking around, another option (maybe the same?) is "bijective base 2": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijective_numeration

Yeah, "bijective base 2" is the same as Daniel's suggestion. Thanks!

Is the algorithm for converting integers to their  binary representations insufficient? I believe the basis representation theorem establishes it is a one to one process.
